# A set of cluster python workers doing scheduled tasks

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I would like to build *a set of cluster workers* (ie droplets in digitalocean or so).

Each worker would be doing a periodic task and sending the results periodically to the main application.

Here is a pseudocode to demontrate the functionality:

**Worker code**

```
while True:
    resultFromLocationXY = calculate_my_local_task()
    send_task_to_the_main_application(resultFromLocationXY)
    time.sleep(5)
```

**Main appplication code**

In the main application I would like to asynchronously evaluate worker results:

```
while True:
    resultFromLocationXY = listen_to_results_from_location('xy') # not blocking, if new results are available, update the results variable

    process_the_results([resultFromLocationXY, resultFromLocationXX, ...])
    time.sleep(5)
```

I have been using the *ipython ipcluster* solution. I was able to create a remote worker and to execute a task by using an apply_async function AND arrange it all in a non blocking way.

BUT: I was not able to make periodic tasks, kind of streaming tasks. Moreover, I would like to have more nodes in one location and stream to the same variable into the main application.

I would prefer a non *ipython* solution.

Comment: What about using the new async library [asyncio](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio.html)? Python 3.4 stable should be out soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me one of the best solution could be something like

- Create a python daemon that will listen for workers. Once a worker send some data, the main daemon will create a thread and start again to listen for other workers
- Create the workers and use cron utility. In that way you could create workers on the fly and within a certain interval. Workers will call the main daemon. Once the main daemon respond with an "OK status" the worker could start

Comment: OK, thank you. I did not think of using cron. What would you use to remotely communicate between the main application and the workers in a non-blocking way?